# $f:Y\to X$ continuous with $f^{-1}(x)$ compact for $x\in X$, does there exist a Borel measurable map $g:X\to Y$?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X,Y$ be Polish, metric spaces. $f:Y\to X$ is a continuous, surjective map and for any $x\in X$, $f^{-1}(x)\subset Y$ is compact. Is it true that there is a injective, Borel measurable map $g:X \to Y$ such that  $f\circ g: X \to X$ is identity?  And $g(X)\subset Y$ is analytic? (If the first question is true, then $X\times g(X) $ is a Borel subset in $X\times Y$, then $g(X)=\pi_Y(X\times g(X))$ is analytic.)

In the book "A course on Borel sets" by S.M. Srivastava, page 204. There is a theorem of Novikov:

Let $X, Y$ be Polish spaces and $\mathcal{A}$ a countably generated sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{B}_X$. Suppose $B\in \mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{B}_Y$ is such that the sections $B_x$ are compact. Then $\pi_X(B)\in \mathcal{A}$, and B admits an $\mathcal{A}$-measurable section.

So just let $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}_X$ and $B=X\times Y$, then the first question follows.

For the proof of Novikov's theorem, first prove that $x\to B_x$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable. Then by a theorem of Kuratowski and Ryll-Nardzewski, page 189:

Let Y be a Polish space, d<1 a compatible complete metric on $Y$, X a nonempty set and $\mathcal{L}$ be an algebra of subsets of X. Then every $\mathcal{L}_{\sigma}$-measurable, closed-valued multifunction $F:X\to Y$ admits an $\mathcal{L}_{\sigma}$-measurable selection.

My question is :  The second theorem need a metric d<1. In the theorem of Novikov, $Y$ may be non-compact metric space. So how to overcome this problem?

Comment: If $d(x,y)$ is any metric, then $d(x,y)/(1+d(x,y))$ is an equivalent metric ${} < 1$.

Comment: Or even $\min\{d(x,y),1\}$, for which the equivalence is immediate. Returning to the question there is also a stronger result by Arsenin-Kunugui stating that Borel sets with $K_\sigma$ sections have a Borel uniformization. Also $g(X)$ will be Borel, not just $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1$, the image of a Borel set through a Borel injection is always Borel.